# Java loop not working

Tags: java, while-loop

So I'm writing a small program but my while-loop does not seem to work, I've looked all over the internet for tutorials and I know that I need to increase J but I can't seem to figure out where because when I get one thing fixed another part stops working!
Could someone please tell me what I have to do to fix this?

```
int j=0;//which group we're checking
            while(response==0){
                {
                    if(inArray(quote.toLowerCase(),greetings[j*2]))
                    {
                        response=2;
                        int r=(int)Math.floor(Math.random()*greetings[(j*2)+1].length);
                        addText("\n-->Miku:\t"+greetings[(j*2)+1][r]);
                        try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("mikuname.txt"))) {
                            String name;
                            while ((name = br.readLine()) != null) {
                            addText(name +"!");
                            }
                        } catch (IOException e1) {
                            // Do something with the IO problem that occurred while reading the file
                        }
                    }
                }
                if(response==0)
                {
                    if(inArray(quote.toLowerCase(),chatBot[j*2]))
                    {
                        response=2;
                        int r=(int)Math.floor(Math.random()*chatBot[(j*2)+1].length);
                        addText("\n-->Miku:\t"+chatBot[(j*2)+1][r]);
                    }
                }
                if(response==0)
                {
                    response=1;
                }
            }
```

Comment: Why you have two `{` after the `while`?

Comment: What do you intend to accomplish with this while loop?

Comment: The way I fix a bug in my code is I use my debugger.  I suggest you step through the code in your debugger to see why it is doing what it is doing.

Comment: I'm creating a chatbot! (Don't worry, it's just because I think it's interesting to make so it won't be spammed everywhere on the internet)

In the top of my code I got 2 strings called Greetings and ChatBot, now, in both of them there's {"something i can say"}{"what the bot will reply"}, and the greetings part works fine because there's only one of those lines, however, in Chatbot, there's more of them for different questions. The problem is, in my loop it seems to only check if what I said is in the first line of Chatbot, I want to make it so it checks the whole thing

Comment: ++j is missing but if you add it you also have to add some bounds checks. E.g. greetings[j*2] <-- why should this be inside the array bounds?

Answer (score 0):

What you probably want to be doing is incrementing j at every iteration. I haven't looked at your logic or tried to understand what you are trying to accomplish, but adding `j++` will make it increment by 1 every iteration of the loop. Otherwise `j*2` will always be 0;

```
int j=0;//which group we're checking
        while(response==0){
            {
                j++;
                if(inArray(quote.toLowerCase(),greetings[j*2]))
                {
                    response=2;
                    int r=(int)Math.floor(Math.random()*greetings[(j*2)+1].length);
                    addText("\n-->Miku:\t"+greetings[(j*2)+1][r]);
                    try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("mikuname.txt"))) {
                        String name;
                        while ((name = br.readLine()) != null) {
                        addText(name +"!");
                        }
                    } catch (IOException e1) {
                        // Do something with the IO problem that occurred while reading the file
                    }
                }
            }
            if(response==0)
            {
                if(inArray(quote.toLowerCase(),chatBot[j*2]))
                {
                    response=2;
                    int r=(int)Math.floor(Math.random()*chatBot[(j*2)+1].length);
                    addText("\n-->Miku:\t"+chatBot[(j*2)+1][r]);
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: You should explain your answer so OP knows his mistake.

Comment: I know I have to make j increment by 1 but I can't seem to let it go through the loop multiple times, like, I can make j increment by 1 but then it will only look at the second lines in chatbot and then it just stops, is there any way I could add a j++ somewhere in the second part of the loop? (where it's looking in chatBot)

Comment: Your while loop was while `response==0` and at the very end of your code, you always set response to 1 if it was still 0 at the end of your first pass. That would prevent the loop from running again. I edited this answer to reflect that code.

Comment: `I haven't looked at your logic or tried to understand what you are trying to accomplish` - then maybe it would be wiser not to advise OP...

Answer (score -1):

For your while loop, use j++ to add 1 to its value through each loop that you do.

while (response==0) {
...
i++;
}